# How to run Liquibase migration without Spring, only by help of Java?

Tags: java, mysql, liquibase

I try to use Liquibase without any adjacent framework, only by help of Java and I faced with a problem how to run Liquibase. I found an example from official documentation:

```
java.sql.Connection connection = openConnection(); //your openConnection logic here
Database database = DatabaseFactory.getInstance().findCorrectDatabaseImplementation(new JdbcConnection(connection));
Liquibase liquibase = new liquibase.Liquibase("path/to/changelog.xml", new ClassLoaderResourceAccessor(), database);
liquibase.update(new Contexts(), new LabelExpression());
```

but I prefer to use a liquibase.property file with settings located in resources folder. When I used a Spring and Hibernate it works fine, I simply write a properties in application.properties file and that's all, but how to act in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about this?

```java
Properties properties = new Properties();
// load properties from classpath
    
java.sql.Connection connection = openConnection(); //your openConnection logic here
Database database = DatabaseFactory.getInstance().findCorrectDatabaseImplementation(new JdbcConnection(connection));
try (Liquibase liquibase = new liquibase.Liquibase("path/to/changelog.xml", new ClassLoaderResourceAccessor(), database)){
  properties.forEach((key, value) -> liquibase.setChangeLogParameter(Objects.toString(key), value));
  liquibase.update(new Contexts(), new LabelExpression());
}
```